# can i createRecord() without using save()?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm learning ember from the scratch and i stumbled upon something i can't quite understand:

```
const newNote = this.store.createRecord('note', {
    content: 'once upon a time...',
});

newNote.save().then(this._redirectToNewNote.bind(this));
```

Is the result of createRecord in the database before saving, or is it like a dummy object? can I use createRecord without saving?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. you can use it without saving, do remember it will be removed from store when you refresh page.

From ember guide

> [createRecord](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_createRecord) is used for creating new records on the client side. This will return a new record in the created.uncommitted state. In order to persist this record to the backend you will need to call record.save().

Comment: can i fake saving it? so i can pass dummy object along without saving it?

Comment: Instead of faking save, You can try [push](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_push) or [pushPayload](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_pushPayload) into store and use [peekRecord](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_peekRecord) to get it and you can use it.

Comment: You can refer this [ember-twiddle demo](https://ember-twiddle.com/fb99f18cd3b4d3e2a4c7?openFiles=application.route.js%2C) . this can be found in [push](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_push)